# Android Studio Generated TODO comments

Tags: android, android-studio, todo

In Eclipse when I generated a new activity or override a method, I would get an automatically generated TODO comment.  Would like to have that in AS also, but can't figure out how to enable that feature.  Can anyone give me a clue on how to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top menu item named **Android Studio** in Mac and then on the **Preferences** option. Now, look for the **Editor** and then on **File and Code Templates** in the side menu.

[**Preferences Path:** Preferences | Editor | File and Code Templates]

Select the **code** tab and edit the **Overridden Method Body** template as shown below.

```
// TODO Implement the method $METHOD_NAME
$CALL_SUPER;
```

[image: Method Code Template]

Click **Ok** and whenever you try to generate an overridden method it generates with the added TODO.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Implement the method onResume
    super.onResume();
}
```

Similarly, you can edit the Activity or Fragment template in the **Other** tab.

[image: Activity File Template]